# How to store a Cookie as persistent data?

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

When connected to the server i get the **Cookies** and store them in a List.

While making connections later i add these cookies to the DefaultHttpClient.

The problem is, when the Application is in **background** for sometime, all the **class data is being lost including the DefaultHttpClient**.

Hence i am **losing the cookie**.

Is there a way to keep the DefaultHttpClient alive forever?

or any better way to store and use cookies?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it from the cookie, then save it in the shared prefferences when the app is killed (e.g. onStop method). Then reload it on onCreate(). Something similar to this:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
   public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
      super.onCreate(state);
      . . .

      // Restore preferences
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      String silent = settings.getString("cookie", null);
      if(cookie == null) {
          // first time, get cookie again and save it
      } else {
          // set cookie manually for HTTPClient
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop(){
      super.onStop();

     // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
     // All objects are from android.context.Context
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("cookie", theCookie);

     // Commit the edits!
     editor.commit();
   }
}
```

(I have omited the code for getting and setting the cookie, I assume that's not a problem)

Comment: can cookie be stored as a String in sharedPreferences? And while reusing it, i must cast it to (Cookie)??

Comment: The cookie VALUE is a string, and you can save that. That is the only thing you need to know to recreate the set the Cookie.

Comment: using **BasicClientCookie("name", "value")** and **BasicHttpContext()**

Comment: Also using **PersistentCookieStore** will do all this automatically??